# Alarm manager don't stop alarm without killing the app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Many people have asked the same question before me but neither of these answered mine. 
I have created an alarm application using **AlarmManager** and **BroadcastReciever**. The ***alarmManager.cancel()*** is not working properly and the alarm ringing until the app is being killed.

I have used the same **Intent** and arguments for setting and cancelling the alarm. 
Following is the code for setting the alarm:

```
 public void startAlarm() {
            alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            intent=new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
    }
```

Stopping Alarm:

```
public void stopAlarm(){
   alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent=new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

}
```

BroadcastReciever class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

}
```

Note: The code is working fine if the alarm is stopped before ringing.
 However once the alarm starts ringing, it cannot be stopped, until the app kill.

Comment: can you add code, where you are calling startAlarm and stopAlarm

Comment: btnSet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    startAlarm();
            }
        });

Comment: btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) { stopAlarm(); } })

Comment: @amit-tiwary  The code is working fine if the alarm is stopped before ringing. However the alarm cannot be stopped while ringing

Answer (score 0):

Try-
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

Comment: Instead of -alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  public void stopAlarm(){
   alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent=new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

}
```